# Angular2: Two-way binding on Map objects

Tags: angular

How i can use two-way binding on Map objects?

The following code doesn't work as expected:

Component:

```
@Component({
    moduleId:    module.id,
    selector:    "my-component",
    templateUrl: "my-component.html",
    styleUrls:   ["my-component.scss"],
})
export class MyComponent {
    myMap: Map<string, Object> = Map<string, Object>()
        .set('first', {text: 'abc'})
        .set('second', {text: 'foo'})
    ;
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="items" *ngFor="let item of myMap.values()">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.text" />
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say "doesn't work as expected'?

Comment: Map<string, Object> is this valid data structure of angularjs2?

Comment: It doesn't bind value changes to page. With array of Objects it's work, but not with Maps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually in this example two-way data binding works as expected. Probably your mistake is in creating Map object:

```
myMap: Map<string, Object> = Map<string, Object>()
```

You have to include `new` keyword before `Map` (because Map Constructor is not callable):

```
myMap: Map<string, Object> = new Map<string, Object>()
        .set('first', {text: 'abc'})
        .set('second', {text: 'foo'})
```

And now everything works as expected. You can check this [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-sherlock-93ocbh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) as well.

> Notice: According to [this Angular issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2246#issuecomment-107212606) on GitHub: Maps have no orders in keys and hence they iteration is unpredictable. This was supported in ng1, but we think it was a mistake and will not be supported in NG2.

One of the simplest solutions for this - is to use `Array.from()` method on `myMap.entries()`:

```
getEntities() {
  // this will return [['first', { text: 'abc' }], ... ]
  // and after mapping we get [{ text: 'abc' }, ...]
  return Array.from(this.myMap.entries()).map(item => item[1]);
}
```

And now we can use it in the template:

```
<div class="items" *ngFor="let item of getEntities()">
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="item.text" />
</div>
```

In this example two-way data-binding works as well.